# SharePoint List - Autocomplete/fill new entries based on the data from the same columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I have just started using SharePoint lists.
I assume my issue is simple but I cannot find a solution for it anywhere so I am asking you.

I have been developing sharepoint list for few days.
I just need it for one project so I am looking for the simplest solution possible.

I need sharepoint to give suggestion when inserting new data into column based on the column contents. Just like excel does by default.
E.g. so if I type "Bob" sharepoint would show me suggestion "Bob Andrew" (assuming that Bob Andrew is already in the column), if I add "Bob R" it would show me suggestion "Bob Richards"(assuming that Bob Richards is already in the column). Obviously newly entered values should also appear in the future suggestions.

I would appreciate any help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not do this kind of thing. There are several different interfaces to edit a list content, but none of them have an intellisense pop up to facilitate entering similar values.

However, if the column is a **Person or Group** column, the default behaviour is that you start typing the name and select from the suggestions that will show up below the input box. This is not base on whether or not this person is already in the list, but based instead on your tenant's Active Directory.

You may also look into Choice columns for as a means of data validation and ease of use of entering data that needs to be consistent.